# How to customize jQuery formBuilder typUserAttrs

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, formbuilder

I've implemented a Rails app with a new feature including a custom form, which I choose jQuery formBuilder as the first option among other plugins. I know I can customize values of each `typeUserAttrs`, but what I want is to hide or disable some of them.

For example: `class`
A simple user might not know what the `class` does, while we developers use it for styling, etc.

The docs or the plugin itself has a `disableFields` option, so I think it should have a `disableTypeUserAttrs`.

Please correct me if I misunderstood documentation. The desired option might exist, but I did not find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure formBuilder by setting the option "disabledAttrs" and adding an array of attributes that you want remove from all type of fields. These attributes are removed from user's form settings.

In your case:

```
var options = {
    disabledAttrs: [
        'className'
    ]
};
```

for example, in the formBuilder's doc format:

```
$(fbEditor).formBuilder(options);
```

You can find the full attributes list here:
https://formbuilder.online/docs/formBuilder/options/disabledAttrs/